# How to get Column values stored in session datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have stored `DataTable` in `Session` as

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)Session["data"];
```

How do I get column values stored in `DataTable` ? Moreover I want to pass column name dynamically.

Let's say I have `DataTable` in which I have columns as Column 0, Column 1, Column 2. So if user selected Column 0, my input column will be Column 0. With that Column name i want store related column values in Database. So, How will be my c# code and SQL query ?

I do have read related questions but not getting exact idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt.Columns["Column 0"]` to get the column by name.

```
DataColumn selectedColumn = dt.Columns["Column 0"];
List<object> allValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[selectedColumn]).ToList();
```

Comment: plz have a look  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233900/how-to-store-column-values-in-particular-column-in-sql-server-200)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value inside a column, 
use

```
dr[<pass column name>]
```

To get the name of all columns 
use

```
dt.Columns[<index>].ColumnName
```