# How to store column values in particular column in SQL server 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

[image: Please find image]

Basically I'm mapping the fields . As you can see in `GridView 2` I've selected specific column names .

Let's consider 1st record, i.e. `1 | id | Column0` ,For `id` I have selected `Column0`, so In Database I want to store column values 1,2,3,4.. under id column.  like below
`id`
`1`
`2`
`3`
So my question is how do I store column values in particular column where I'm passing column name, column values dynamically ?

Here's a code what I've done , I know its wrong.

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtMap = new DataTable();
    dtMap.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Source", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Destination", typeof(string)) });

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
        string source = GridView2.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        string destination = ((DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Value;


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["data"];
        DataColumn selectedColumn = dt.Columns[destination];
        List<object> allValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[selectedColumn]).ToList();

        connection();
        strsql = "Insert into F3_BC_Product_Mapping_Data (@source) values (@value) ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", destination);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", allValues);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        dtMap.Rows.Add(id, source, destination);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Insert-Update-Edit-Delete-record-in-GridView-using-SqlDataSource-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: i read your post 5 times and still got nothing. why values dynamic?

Comment: Okay I'll try to explain. I have bind column name from first grid view to drop down list of second grid view. Now if i selected Column 1 for kewordfilter, i want to store Column 1 values under different table with column name as keyword filter and values as Column 1 values.

Comment: @Badiparmagi and values are dynamic because every time column name are not fixed and values are different

Comment: ok. now i got you. let me see what i can do. @samkokane

Comment: @samkokane check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something. Check this and let me know please.

```
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text);
                string source = GridView1.Rows[gr.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
                string destination = ((DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedItem.Value;


                InsertDynamicColumn(source, destination);
            }
```

here is my  `InsertDynamicColumn(string source, string destination)` method.  after i got my DataTable from `Session` i filtered Datatable based on destination parameter and put result to a new list. the rest is easy. insert value from list to source.

```
    private void InsertDynamicColumn(string source, string destination)
    {
        //dt from Session
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Session["myData"];

        //list filtered by Column name
        var list = from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       select new
                       {
                           colX = t.Field<string>(destination),// "ColX"
                       };

        //new filtered list.
        var listOfColx = list.ToList();


        //loop through list and insert values to source from parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfColx.Count; i++)
        {
            connection();
            strsql = string.Format("Insert into F3_BC_Product_Mapping_Data ({0}) values (@value) ", source);
            cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", listOfColx[i]);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this and let You know

Comment: @samkokane glad to help.